How to move broswer static content to CDN in Angular 17 SSR
We are building SEO optimised site using Angular 17 SSR. To make our site load faster we decided to move statics files to S3 and Added s3's cdn path instead of browswer path for serving the static files like html , css , javascripts etc.
For this, we build the project and moved files from browser folder to s3 bucket and got the cdn url for it.
Below is our server.ts file.
import { CommonEngine } from '@angular/ssr';
import express from 'express';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';
import { dirname, join } from 'node:path';
import AppServerModule from './src/main.server';


// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export async function app(): Promise<express.Express> {
  const server = express();

  const serverDistFolder = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
  // const browserDistFolder = resolve(serverDistFolder, '../browser');
  const browserDistFolder: string = "https://custom-cdn.something.co";
  const indexHtml = join(serverDistFolder, 'index.server.html');

  const commonEngine = new CommonEngine();

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', browserDistFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  // server.get('*.*', express.static(browserDistFolder, {
  //   maxAge: '1y'
  // }));

  // All regular routes use the Angular engine
  server.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    const { protocol, originalUrl, baseUrl, headers } = req;

    commonEngine
      .render({
        bootstrap: AppServerModule,
        inlineCriticalCss: false,
        documentFilePath: indexHtml,
        url: `${protocol}://${headers.host}${originalUrl}`,
        publicPath: browserDistFolder,
      })
      .then((html) => res.send(html))
      .catch((err) => next(err));
  });


  return server;
}

async function run(): Promise<void> {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  (await server).listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

run();

Now when we ran it , we got broken page and javascript is not working.
Got this error multiple times for every js chunks,
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
I tried adding this
// Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(browserDistFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

but result is same.
I guess, every files getting served as text/html and because of it, css, images and js are not working.
Is this S3 issue or Issue from the code?
What are we missing here?
Any help or feedback would be helpful.

I had the same problem, I realised that it is necessary to request the static files from the cdn through an http request. The code that worked for me is as follows:
// ...Default imports
import path from 'node:path';

export function app(): express.Express {

  // ...Default variables  
  const browserDistFolder = 'https://custom-cdn.something.co';

  const hasExtension = (filePath: string): boolean => {
    return path.extname(filePath) !== '';
  }

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', browserDistFolder);    
  server.get('**', async (req, res) => {
    try {        
        let requestPath = req.path;

        if (!hasExtension(requestPath)) {
            requestPath += '/index.html';
        }
        
        const path = `${browserDistFolder}${requestPath}`;
        const response = await fetch(path);
             
        if (!response.ok) {
            res.status(response.status).send('Error message');
            return;
        }

        const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type') ?? '';

        res.set('Content-Type', contentType);

        if (contentType.includes('text') || contentType.includes('json')) {            
            const body = await response.text();
            res.send(body);
        } 
        else {            
            const arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
            const buffer = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer);
            res.send(buffer);
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching:', error);
        res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    }
  });

  // Angular default code to render html (no changes made)
  server.get('**', (req, res, next) => {...});

  return server;
}

// Default code to run server (no changes made)    
function run(): void {...}

run();

A small explanation of the code:
When the project is created, by default an express middleware is configured to serve static files from browserDistFolder.
  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', browserDistFolder);  
  server.get('**', express.static(browserDistFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y',
    index: 'index.html',
  }));

But when you use a cdn, you have to set up your own middleware to fetch the files from the cdn and serve them to the application. To do this you can make an http request with fetch and get the files from the cdn.
let requestPath = req.path;

const path = `${browserDistFolder}${requestPath}`;
const response = await fetch(path);
        
if (!response.ok) {
    res.status(response.status).send('Error message');
    return;
}

const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type') ?? '';

res.set('Content-Type', contentType);

You have to check the content type, for html, js or css files, you can convert the response body to text format. But the files that are of type img, video, fonts, etc. You have to convert the response body to buffer so that it can be read correctly by the browser.
if (contentType.includes('text') || contentType.includes('json')) {            
    const body = await response.text();
    res.send(body);
} 
else {            
    const arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
    const buffer = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer);
    res.send(buffer);
}

If you have pre-rendered routes enabled in Angular, you need to check if the requested resource has an extension or not, because when the application requests these pre-rendered routes, the request path is just the folder name of the pre-rendered route without the index.html.
   let requestPath = req.path; // example: my-pre-rendered-route

   if (!hasExtension(requestPath)) { // true
        requestPath += '/index.html'; // my-pre-rendered-route/index.html
   }

If the /index.html is not added, the pre-rendered route will not load.

Thanks, @Leo for your reply,  But I think this approach defeats the purpose of CDN.
Here browser will make to request to my server and then the server will request CDN to get the content.
I think this will make the overall process slow.
I haven't tried it though.
I expect that the browser directly takes content from CDN. Let me know if it's possible.
